# Can't get audio over GStreamer udpsrc element

Tags: gstreamer, audio-streaming

I'm trying to play audio (WAV) file using Gstreamer udpsrc element with no success. Playing audio from a file works just fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=sp5.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! volume volume=1 ! autoaudiosink
```

But when running this in one terminal:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5200 ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! volume volume=1 ! autoaudiosink
```

and this in another:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=sp5.wav ! udpsink host=localhost port=5200
```

can't get any audio out (and Wireshark shows packets are going across). Trying the last command from a different PC didn't make any difference.

Running Gstreamer version 1.14.4.
Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: You will need a network protocol.

Comment: guess that's a clue, thanks; some link to relevant info would be even better; will have a look around